# Why was there silence in heaven for half an hour?

Tags: revelation

We read revelation 8:1 "when the Lamb opened the seventh seal, there was silence in heaven for about half an hour". When we imagine of heaven it would be full of joyful noice singing hallelujeh song, praising God's glory (some scripture also says about it). But this shows different so can you help me to understand why it was silent for half an hour.